# Why is my list argument turning into a tuple when calling a smart contract function in python using Web3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smartcontracts, web3py

"Could not identify the intended function with name `swapExactNATIVEForTokens`, positional arguments with type(s) `int,(int,int,(address,address)),address,int` and keyword arguments with type(s) `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `swapExactNATIVEForTokens`: ['swapExactNATIVEForTokens(uint256,(uint256[],uint8[],address[]),address,uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types."

```
swap_txn = btc_bridge_contract.functions.swapExactNATIVEForTokens(
        amountOfMinBtc, (10, 1, list), address, deadline
    ).build_transaction({
        'from': address,
        'value': amount_avax,
        'gas': 300000,
        'gasPrice': gas_price,
        'nonce': nonce,
    })
```

That is my code sample, list = ['0xB31f66AA3C1e785363F0875A1B74E27b85FD66c7', '0x152b9d0FdC40C096757F570A51E494bd4b943E50']
but still going to tuple, not the array

I am trying to invoke function on smart contract, but getting an error, cause my array appears as tuple of 2 addresses

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`swap_txn = btc_bridge_contract.functions.swapExactNATIVEForTokens( amountOfMinBtc, ([10], [1], list), address, deadline ).build_transaction({ 'from': address, 'value': amount_avax, 'gas': 300000, 'gasPrice': gas_price, 'nonce': nonce, })`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).